# Textbox Object Reference

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How can I reference a `TextBox` object(say textBox1) in another custom class in form1.cs file?

In `myclass`, I've written `textBox1`, but intelliSense didn't suggest it to me. Changing private to public doesn't solve it.

Here is the sample code of form1.cs

```
namespace Calculator {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            // InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        class myclass {
            // What can I do to make texbox1 show up in intelliSense here? 
            // textBox1
        }

        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer and more understandable, so that we can answer it.

Comment: And please post some code.

Comment: BTW, the preferred way of doing what Robert Harvey said is showing us some code.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can change Modifiers in the Design category in the Properties window for the control from `private` to `public`. That should let you get at it from elsewhere.

Comment: already changed private to public . but it does'nt work.

Comment: People are too quick to close. You asked the OP to edit the question and show code... but turn right around and close the question... preventing anyone from answering...

Comment: @Inisheer The question was closed because the OP was very slow to respond. Anyway I cast a reopen vote.

Comment: When the original poster edits the question, I think it is now automatically put in the reopen queue, @Inisheer.

Comment: @DonKirkby Noooooooo! It gets put in the reopen queue! Nooooooo!

Comment: Are you disagreeing, @JeremyThompson, or just moaning? [According to meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171718) a closed question is put in the reopen queue if the asker edits it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to refrence an object created by Desginer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422711/how-to-refrence-an-object-created-by-desginer)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reference it directly in the scope of `myClass`, then declare it as static.

Or you would need an instance of `Form1`, but that won't allow you declare a reference to it in the class definition scope, you need to instantiate the instance of `Form1` in constructor(or type initializer) that you can assign it to the member of `myClass`.

```
namespace Calculator {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        class myclass {
            TextBox textBox3=Form1.textBox1;
            TextBox textBox4;
            Form1 form1;

            public myclass() {
                form1=new Form1();
                textBox4=form1.textBox2;
            }
        }

        static public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
    }
}
```

---

update:

For the concerning of current instance of `Form1`, following is **one of the various ways** to pass the current instance when instantiate `myclass`

```
namespace Calculator {
    public partial class Form1: Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1=textBox2; // demonstration for "static make sense"

            var x=new Form1.myclass {
                form1=this
            };

            // now x.textBox3 is reference to textBox2
        }

        public class myclass {
            TextBox textBox3=Form1.textBox1;
            TextBox textBox4;
            internal Form1 form1;

            public myclass() {
                // form1=new Form1();
                textBox4=form1.textBox2;
            }
        }

        static public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just code for mindless copy and pasting is not very useful to future visitors with similar, but not exactly the same problem. For code blocks of this length, there should be some kind of an explanation that describes what the code does.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper its cool, Ken's been the first to answer this reopened question and put in detail... some of us need a little time.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Better saying now while the author is still around. There are anough unfinished, yet accepted answer stubs lying around on SO, which were well helpful for the OP (thus the acceptance), but are useless to anyone else for lack of an explanation. Nonetheless, good work now with the explanation - +1 :-)

Comment: I did't know I was the first. When it was still a closed question, I tried helping to improve the question and done that with revision 7, then it reopened. I put the code, save, then add explanation. And then, I revise.

Comment: @Ken Kin your solution not answer a question. In question user want reference of textbox from used instance of Form1. Your references of static TetxBox and new(Empty) instance of form. Answer of DonKirkby is right on my opinion

Comment: @Fabio: Are you talking to @O.R.Mapper or to me? If to me, what this answered that ***how can texbox1 show up in intelliSense***. For an existing instance of `Form1`, there're ***various*** way to achieve.

Comment: @Ken Kin, yes was talking to you. About getting a textbox in IntellSense you was right, but seems no sense to using static TextBox of form(Then need all form change to static - no sense) and with New Form same -> no sense sorry. Question was(first line) **How can I reference a TextBox object**

Comment: @Fabio: As I told, there're various way to do. This is a conceptual sample shows the ways how to reference to the member.

Answer (score 3):

Nested types have a static relationship to their containing types. That means that by default, they don't have access to any particular instance of the containing type. If you want the inner type to access some field from the containing type, you have to pass an instance to the inner type. The most common way is to pass an instance to the nested type's constructor.

```
public partial class Form1: Form {
    public Form1() {
        // InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    class myclass {
        private Form1 parent;

        public myclass(Form1 parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void DoSomething() {
            parent.textBox1.Text = "Hello, World!";
        }
    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
}
```