# How to refrence an object created by Desginer

Tags: c#, oop, designer

(I'm using default Visual Studio names) How can I reference a texbox object(texbox1) in another custom class in form1.cs file(a class within "public partial class Form1 : Form")

here is my code. In myclass I've written textBox1, but intelisense didn't suggest it to me. I mean. what can I do to make texbox1 show up in intelisence in this situation? changing private to public in form1.Desginer.cs does'nt solve it. plaease answer.

```
namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }


        class myclass 
        {

           textBox1

        }
}
```

Comment: Why is `myclass` a nested class of `MyForm`? C# nested classes don't share data like Java does.

Comment: @AbZy: Arguably, the other question should be closed, as this one somehow seems a tad clearer IMO.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I marked this as duplicate because we helped to reopen the other question so that the OP gets some answers. It was so wrong to post the question again.

Comment: @AbZy: Possibly. The other question does not mention an important constraint that the author seems to have, though, namely that the declaration of the text box must not be changed (because it is IDE-generated). That is why I consider this question to be the clearer variant (which should probably be more important than the creation order).

Answer (score 0):

The WinForms designer makes components private by default, and ideally you should not expose components (such as controls) directly because it breaks encapsulation. You should proxy fields that you want to share, like so:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form {

    private TextBox _textbox1; // this field exists in the MyForm.designer.cs file

    // this property should be in your MyForm.cs file
    public String TextBox1Value {
        get { return _textbox1.Text; }
        set { _textbox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

That way you can share data between forms but also maintain encapsulation (though you should choose a more descrptive name than the `TextBox1Value` I chose.

Comment: thank u for this simple example.

Comment: but it givee me this error:

Comment: cannot access a non static member of outer type ....

Comment: Right, you need to create an *instance* of `MyForm` first.

Answer (score 0):

In your nested class `myclass`, you do not specify which *instance* of the `Form1` class you are referring to. Add a reference to a particular instance of `Form1`, then you will be able to access its `textBox1` member.

Customarily, this can be done like so:

```
class myclass
{
    public myclass(Form1 owner)
    {
        if (owner == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("owner");
        }

        this.owner = owner;
    }

    private readonly Form1 owner;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        owner.textBox1.Text = "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

This code uses various patterns that are used in such situations:

- `owner` is set in the constructor, thereby ensuring that it is *never* `null`
- adding to this, `null` is rejected by the constructor
- the `owner` member is `readonly`, so it is safe to say that it will not change during the lifetime of a given `myclass` instance

Within a method of `Form1`, you can then create a `myclass` instance linked to the current `Form1` instance by invoking `new myclass(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just reference it in your nested class as its part of the `Form1` class, you will have to pass in a reference

Example:

```
class myclass 
{
    public TextBox MyTextBox { get; set; }

    public MyClass(TextBox textbox)
    {
        MyTextBox = textbox;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Form1` class where you created the `MyClass` instance you can pass in your `TextBox`

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this.textBox1);
```